# How do I insert text here in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have javascript that will open this window, but I need after opening this chat to insert text [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ugu.png) and send it. Also would appreciated if you could help me improve my code.

```
setInterval(function acceptor() {
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('button green');
    for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
        if (btn[i].innerText.indexOf('Accept') > -1) {
            btn[i].click();
            console.log('Accepted in to IMs');
        }
    }
}, 1000);

console.log('Acceptor started');

setInterval(function getnick() {
    var cnt = document.getElementsByClassName('notificationsSlider');
    for (var j = 0; j < cnt.length; j++) {
        if (cnt[j].innerText.indexOf('is now your contact') > -1) {
            var nickname = cnt[j].innerText;
            var onlynickname = nickname.split(' is now your contact').shift();
            console.log(onlynickname);
            var contactlist = document.getElementsByClassName('userName');
    for (var k = 0; k < contactlist.length; k++) {
        if (contactlist[k].innerText.indexOf(onlynickname) > -1) {
            contactlist[k].click();
            console.log('Opened chat');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, 3500);

console.log('Openner started');
```

EDIT:

I just found out that it won't be that easy I guess. At first point: I am trying to make JS to accept contact request, open chat wih it and post/send auto message to the accepted contact.

Today I found out that that "text box" - thing where I need to insert my custom auto message text is changing dynamically.

When my code that so far opens the chat with the contact it looks like this. `<br data-text="true">`

After I insert there some text by myself it changes to this: `<span data-text="true">I inserted text here</span>`

Could anyone help me out how to write js that will after oppening chat also insert my custome message there?

Comment: Can you add some more information?  Is part of this working?  Where are you having trouble?  Is there a little bit of the source DOM/HTML you could add to clarify which parts of this are working or not working?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you stuck at? I think you'll need to be a little more specific with what you're having difficulties with. There's enough resource on this website to guide you through different selectors, appending data and I can see by your snippet, how to simulate click events.

Comment: @Adriani6 As I provided in screenshot I am trying to write JS for inputting text there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8ugu.png I am not sure if I have firstly use something what will click on blank space where I can input that text or to use something like this: document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";. I also don't know what Id/Class that blank space has- there is only- <span data-text="true">HERE IS VALUE which I want to insert by javascript</span>

Comment: @wsupreme That would indicate that it has a data attribute only - you can query an element/elements using data attributes too.

Comment: @Adriani6 I've put a rather clunky method of finding the right span element into my answer - I'm sure there must be a better way but I can't find it. Any help/improvements would be welcome.

Comment: @Adriani6 

I've edited the post and I found out that: No content. <br data-text="true"> When I manually add content it looks like - content.<span data-text="true">It changes after inputing value manually</span>. Could you please help me out how to insert any text when it's empty there by js?

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how to insert text into a particular span element. Inserting text into an element can be done by the e.g. el.innerHTML='The text';

To do that you first have to find the element. Looking at the screenshot provided it seems as though the span element needed is the only one with a data-text="true". We therefore need to find that.

You ask for suggestions to improve your code. If this bit is your code and you are able to add things to your HTML I would suggest you think about giving elements which are unique and which you want to use unique identifiers. For example:

```
<span id="datatext"></span>
```

JavaScript can then find it quite simply:

```
el=document.getElementById('datatext');
```

If you aren't in a position to do that then the only way I can think of is to look at all the span elements in the document and find those which have data-text="true"

Here is an example of doing that on a document with a few spans - just one of which has that attribute. (thanks to @Adriani6 for the querySelectorAll information)

```
<span data-text='false']></span>
<span data-text='true']></span>
<span data-somethingelse='true']></span>
<span data-number='3']></span>

<script>
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("[data-text='true']");
if (spans.length==1) {
  console.log('Success I have found the span element required.');
  spans[0].innerHTML='The text you want to put in';
}
else {
  console.log('Help, there are '+ spans.length + ' span elements with data-text="true" so I do not know where to put the text');
}
</script>
```

It isn't really possible to be of great help with your Javascript code as there isn't enough information to know exactly what it is trying to do. One thing I noted was that you are simulating clicks (rather than waiting for the user to click) the green buttons and I wonder if that is what you intended - and if it is why you need a seconds pause before doing so? [the OP has clarified that].

Comment: @A Haworth thank you, will test it for sure. I am trying to make some kinda 'bot' that will accept contact requests and auto reply them an auto-message. 
I also found out that after openning my chat window there is allways blank space at first so it starts like this: https://prnt.sc/ugogkq after text input it switches to this: https://prnt.sc/ugohds

Comment: No need to iterate all spans, this is very inefficient. You can target the span with the right data attribute using `document.querySelectorAll("[data-text='true']");`.

Comment: @Adriani6 thanks - that's very much more readable/sensible. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @AHaworth I've edited the post and I found out that: No content. <br data-text="true"> When I manually add content it looks like - content.<span data-text="true">It changes after inputing value manually</span>. Could you please help me out how to insert any text when it's empty there by js? –

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Do you have a <span data-text="true"><span> in your original document? If so the code in the answer will put some text into it. Are you saying that actually your initial document has <br data-text="true"> in it instead? That doesn't look like a 'proper' element.

Comment: @AHaworth original it has <br data-text="true"> When I manually insert text it looks like: 
<span data-text="true">same element after text inputted manually</span>

Comment: How are you manually inserting text? (e.g. through dev tools or...)